# Angular 5 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Tags: node.js, angular, mean

I got this error on my chrome's console :

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'toLowerCase' of undefined

On DashboardComponent.html:5 :

```
<div class="mdl-grid center-items">
  <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col">
      <mat-form-field class="search-form-field">
          <input matInput type="text" name="searchCompany" placeholder="Search" [(ngModel)]="searchCompany"/>
          <button *ngIf="searchCompany" matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear" (click)="searchCompany=''">
            <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
          </button>
      </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my CompanyFilterPipe class :

```
import { PipeTransform, Pipe } from "@angular/core";
import { Company } from "../../models/company.model";

@Pipe({
    name : 'companyFilter'
})
export class CompanyFilterPipe implements PipeTransform{
    transform(companies:Company[], searchCompany:String) : Company[]{
        const value = searchCompany.toLowerCase();
        if(!companies == !searchCompany){
            return companies;
        }
        return companies.filter(companies => companies.perusahaan.toLowerCase().indexOf(value) !== -1);
    }

}
```

I have declare the CompanyFilterPipe on app.module.ts, but it's not work as well, how I can fix this? Thank you.

Comment: But you're not using `companyFilter ` anywhere in your template?

Comment: I just use in this page only.

Comment: use an if to take account that searchCompany is not null: if (searchCompany){...}else{return []} //return an empty array

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the property `perusahaan` is undefined on `company` object. Try stating it in the `Company` type, or in the function declaration use `companies:any[]`. Also you should use a different variable name inside the filter.

**EDIT**

1) Use `searchCompanies:string` instead of String

2) `!companies == !searchCompany` will always be true unless either of the fields is empty, so your lower return statement isn't reached.

3) Using `companies.filter(companies =>..` will clash as you are giving the same names to the array and the filter component. Use it like: `source.pipe(filter(num => num > 5))`

4) Check if searchCompany isn't empty.

Comment: I have defined it, I use it for give the name for company.

Comment: Try to use any[] declaration or console.log companies.perusahaan to see what is actually being passed.

Comment: I created the export class Company{
    perusahaan       : String;} but it returns undefined when I check company.perusahaan. Why it happen?

Comment: But then I console.log(companies) it returns an my data in object inside array.

Comment: I found where the problem is in return companies; but why? when I delete the return companies, the filter is working, but I still get the error on my console.

Comment: Check the edits. These should most probably resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in declaration of the Pipe. The Pipe is getting triggered, that's why you are receiving an error related to the logic written inside the Pipe.

toLowerCase() method should be applied only on strings.

As the error says it Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined, you need to verify the inputs sent to the Pipe. toLowerCase() is applied for two properties, 'searchCompany' and 'companies.perusahaan', please place a debugger within the Pipe and verify that the value of both these properties are string.

Comment: When I check the value in console.log, it returns input what I have type in the input.

Comment: You mean the value of searchCompany?

Comment: yap, value of searchCompany.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding :

```
if(!searchCompany){
    return companies;
}
```

So when the search input is null, I return the companies, but when the input has value, it will

```
return companies.filter(companies => companies.perusahaan.toLowerCase().indexOf(value) !== -1);
```

Thanks for helping me kind people :)